# What are all the common ways to read a file in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, file-io

What are all the common ways to read a file in Ruby?

For instance, here is one method:

```
fileObj = File.new($fileName, "r")
while (line = fileObj.gets)
  puts(line)
end
fileObj.close
```

I know Ruby is extremely flexible. What are the benefits/drawbacks of each approach?

Comment: I don't think the current winning answer is correct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read lines of a file in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012930/how-to-read-lines-of-a-file-in-ruby)

Answer (score 281, accepted):

```
File.open("my/file/path", "r") do |f|
  f.each_line do |line|
    puts line
  end
end
# File is closed automatically at end of block
```

It is also possible to explicitly close file after as above (pass a block to `open` closes it for you):

```
f = File.open("my/file/path", "r")
f.each_line do |line|
  puts line
end
f.close
```

Comment: This is hardly idiomatic Ruby. Use `foreach` instead of `open` and dispense with the `each_line` block.

Comment: `f.each { |line| ... }` and `f.each_line { |line| ... }` seem to have the same behavior (at least in Ruby 2.0.0).

Answer (score 377):

The easiest way if the file isn't too long is:

```
puts File.read(file_name)
```

Indeed, `IO.read` or `File.read` automatically close the file, so there is no need to use `File.open` with a block.

Comment: `IO.read` or `File.read` also automatically close the file, though your wording makes it sound like they do not.

Comment: he already said "if the file isn't too long". Suits my case perfectly.

Answer (score 241):

Be wary of "slurping" files. That's when you read the entire file into memory at once.

The problem is that it doesn't scale well. You could be developing code with a reasonably sized file, then put it into production and suddenly find you're trying to read files measuring in gigabytes, and your host is freezing up as it tries to read and allocate memory.

Line-by-line I/O is very fast, and almost always as effective as slurping. It's surprisingly fast actually.

I like to use:

```
IO.foreach("testfile") { |x| print "GOT ", x }
```

or

```
File.foreach('testfile') { |x| print "GOT", x }
```

File inherits from IO, and `foreach` is in IO, so you can use either.

I have some benchmarks showing the impact of trying to read big files via `read` vs. line-by-line I/O at "https://stackoverflow.com/q/25189262/128421".

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I've got a file with five million lines, and really didn't want that loaded into memory.

Comment: I wonder why is file "slurping" called like that? According [this dictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/slurp) slurp means "To eat or drink noisily" .

Comment: It comes from programming history. Here's a starting point https://www.perl.com/article/21/2013/4/21/Read-an-entire-file-into-a-string/

Answer (score 75):

You can read the file all at once:

```
content = File.readlines 'file.txt'
content.each_with_index{|line, i| puts "#{i+1}: #{line}"}
```

When the file is large, or may be large, it is usually better to process it line-by-line:

```
File.foreach( 'file.txt' ) do |line|
  puts line
end
```

Sometimes you want access to the file handle though or control the reads yourself:

```
File.open( 'file.txt' ) do |f|
  loop do
    break if not line = f.gets
    puts "#{f.lineno}: #{line}"
  end
end
```

In case of binary files, you may specify a nil-separator and a block size, like so:

```
File.open('file.bin', 'rb') do |f|
  loop do
    break if not buf = f.gets(nil, 80)
    puts buf.unpack('H*')
  end
end
```

Finally you can do it without a block, for example when processing multiple files simultaneously. In that case the file must be explicitly closed (improved as per comment of @antinome):

```
begin
  f = File.open 'file.txt'
  while line = f.gets
    puts line
  end
ensure
  f.close
end
```

References: [File API](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/File.html) and the [IO API](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html).

Comment: There is no `for_each` in File or IO. Use [`foreach`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-c-foreach) instead.

Comment: I usually use the Sublime Text editor, with the RubyMarkers plugin, when documenting code to be used in answers here. It makes it really easy to show intermediate results, similar to using IRB. Also the Seeing Is Believing plugin for Sublime Text 2 is really powerful.

Comment: Great answer. For the last example I might suggest using  `while` instead of `loop` and using `ensure` to ensure the file gets closed even if an exception is raised. Like this (replace semi-colons with newlines): `begin; f = File.open('testfile'); while line = f.gets; puts line; end; ensure; f.close; end`.

Comment: yeah that is much better @antinome, improved the answer. thanks!

Answer (score 31):

One simple method is to use [`readlines`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref_c_io.html#IO.readlines):

```
my_array = IO.readlines('filename.txt')
```

Each line in the input file will be an entry in the array.  The method handles opening and closing the file for you.

Comment: As with `read` or any variant, this will pull the entire file into memory, which can cause major problems if the file is larger than the memory available. In addition, because it's an array, Ruby has to create the array, slowing the process additionally.

Answer (score 25):

```
file_content = File.read('filename with extension');
puts file_content;
```

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-read

Answer (score 9):

I usually do this:

```
open(path_in_string, &:read)
```

This will give you the whole text as a string object. It works only under Ruby 1.9.

Comment: This is nice and short! Does it close the file too?

Comment: It closes it, but it's not scalable so be careful.

Answer (score 4):

if the file is small (slurping):

```
puts File.read("filename.txt")
```

if the file is big (streaming):

```
File.foreach("filename.txt") { |line| puts line }
```

Answer (score 3):

return last *n* lines from your_file.log or .txt

```
path = File.join(Rails.root, 'your_folder','your_file.log')

last_100_lines = `tail -n 100 #{path}`
```

Answer (score 3):

An even more efficient way is streaming by asking the operating system’s kernel to open a file, then read bytes from it bit by bit. When reading a file per line in Ruby, data is taken from the file 512 bytes at a time and split up in “lines” after that.

By buffering the file’s content, the number of I/O calls is reduced while dividing the file in logical chunks.

Example:

Add this class to your app as a service object:

```
class MyIO
  def initialize(filename)
    fd = IO.sysopen(filename)
    @io = IO.new(fd)
    @buffer = ""
  end

  def each(&block)
    @buffer << @io.sysread(512) until @buffer.include?($/)

    line, @buffer = @buffer.split($/, 2)

    block.call(line)
    each(&block)
  rescue EOFError
    @io.close
 end
end
```

Call it and pass the `:each` method a block:

```
filename = './somewhere/large-file-4gb.txt'
MyIO.new(filename).each{|x| puts x }
```

Read about it here in this detailed post:

[Ruby Magic Slurping & Streaming Files By AppSignal](https://blog.appsignal.com/2018/07/10/ruby-magic-slurping-and-streaming-files.html)

Comment: Watch out: that code will ignore the last line if it doesn't end with a linefeed (at least in Linux).

Comment: I think inserting "block.call(@buffer)" before "@io.close" will pick up the missing incomplete line. However, I have played with Ruby only one day so I could well be wrong. It worked in my application :)

Comment: After reading the AppSignal post it seems that there has been a small misunderstanding here.  The code you copied out of that post which does a buffered IO is an example implementation of what Ruby actually does with File.foreach, or IO.foreach (which are the same method).  They should be used, and you do not need reimplement them like this.

Comment: @PeterH.Boling I'm also for the use-and-don't-reimplement mentality most of the time. But ruby does allow us to open up things and poke at their insides without shame it's one of it's perks.
There is no real 'should' or 'should not' especially in ruby/rails.
As long as you know what you are doing, and you write tests for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
content = `cat file`
```

I think this method is the most "uncommon" one. Maybe it is kind of tricky, but it works if `cat` is installed.

Comment: A handy trick, but calling out to the shell has a lot of pitfalls, including 1) the commands may differ on different OS's, 2) you may need to escape spaces in the filename. You're much better off using Ruby built-in functions, e.g. `content = File.read(filename)`