# How do I read line by line a text file in ruby (hosting it on s3)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, text, import, heroku

I know I've done this before and found a simple set of code, but I cannot remember or find it :(.

I have a text file of records I want to import into my Rails 3 application.

Each line represents a record.  Potentially it may be tab delimited for the attributes, but am fine with just a single value as well.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 48):

```
File.open("my/file/path", "r").each_line do |line|
  # name: "Angela"    job: "Writer"    ...
  data = line.split(/\t/)
  name, job = data.map{|d| d.split(": ")[1] }.flatten
end
```

Related topic

[What are all the common ways to read a file in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545068/ruby-all-ways-to-read-from-file/5545284#5545284)

Comment: This doesn't address the problem of the file being on s3

Comment: @Patm, oh I see :) But at the moment all three answerers were answering the topic wasn't about S3. It was just `How do I read line by line a text file in ruby`

Comment: Is there a way to do so when the file sits in s3?

Comment: @Angela File.open("insert url here")

Comment: Does this close the file properly?

Comment: @fl00r What makes you think that this code properly closes the file? See: `a = File.open('path', 'r'); a.each_line do |line| puts line end; puts a.closed?` prints `false`!

Comment: @fl00r According to the link you are quoting, an explicit `close` is necessary.

Answer (score 21):

You want [`IO.foreach`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M000881):

```
IO.foreach('foo.txt') do |line|
  # process the line of text here
end
```

Alternatively, if it really is tab-delimited, you might want to use the [CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/index.html) library:

```
File.open('foo.txt') do |f|
  CSV.foreach(f, col_sep:"\t") do |csv_row|
    # All parsed for you
  end
end
```

Comment: Does IO.foreach provide an iterator?

Answer (score 4):

```
  IO.foreach("input.txt") do |line| 
    out.puts line
    # You might be able to use split or something to get attributes
    atts = line.split
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `OpenURI` (http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html)? You would have to make your files accessible from S3.

Or try using de `aws-sdk` gem (http://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby).

Comment: the files would have permission , but I guess it still needs to be able to use the answer at the top using the File class to go through it and I wasn't clear it could.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [OpenURI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html) to read remote or local files.

Assuming that your model has an attachment named `file`:

```
# If object is stored in amazon S3, access it through url
file_path = record.file.respond_to?(:s3_object) ? record.file.url : record.file.path
open(file_path) do |file|
  file.each_line do |line|
    # In your case, you can split items using tabs
    line.split("\t").each do |item|
      # Process item
    end
  end
end
```