# How to read lines of a file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, line-endings

I was trying to use the following code to read lines from a file. But when reading a [file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/559353/rss20.xml.txt), the contents are all in one line:

```
line_num=0
File.open('xxx.txt').each do |line|
  print "#{line_num += 1} #{line}"
end
```

But this [file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/559353/new.txt) prints each line separately.

---

I have to use stdin, like `ruby my_prog.rb < file.txt`, where I can't assume what the line-ending character is that the file uses. How can I handle it?

Comment: Rather than doing `line_num = 0`, you could use `each.each_with_index` or possibly `each.with_index`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/25189262/128421 for why line-by-line IO is preferred over using `read`.

Comment: Use `line.chomp` to handle the line endings (courtesy of [@SreenivasanAC](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24483583/165673))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are all the common ways to read a file in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545068/what-are-all-the-common-ways-to-read-a-file-in-ruby)

Comment: I'd recommend reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189262/why-is-slurping-a-file-bad

Answer (score 153, accepted):

I believe my answer covers your new concerns about handling any type of line endings since both `"\r\n"` and `"\r"` are converted to Linux standard `"\n"` before parsing the lines.

To support the `"\r"` EOL character along with the regular `"\n"`, and `"\r\n"` from Windows, here's what I would do:

```
line_num=0
text=File.open('xxx.txt').read
text.gsub!(/\r\n?/, "\n")
text.each_line do |line|
  print "#{line_num += 1} #{line}"
end
```

Of course this could be a bad idea on very large files since it means loading the whole file into memory.

Comment: That regex didn't work for me. Unix format uses \n, windows \r\n, mac uses \n -- .gsub(/(\r|\n)+/,"\n") worked for me with all cases.

Comment: Correct regex should be ```/\r?\n/``` which will cover both \r\n and \n without combining empty lines as Pod's comment would do

Comment: This will read the entire file into memory, which could be impossible depending on how large the file is.

Comment: I think instead of text=File.open('xxx.txt').read you want File.read('xxx.txt'). Otherwise you need to close the file ?

Comment: This method is very highly inefficient, talabes answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/17415655/228589 is the best answer. Please verify the implementation these two methods.

Comment: @AntoineToulme No, ruby will automatically close the file when gc. The real point is we should use Jonathan answer.

Comment: This is not the ruby way. The answer below shows the right behavior.

Answer (score 603):

Ruby does have a method for this:

```rb
File.readlines('foo', chomp: true).each do |line|
    puts(line)
end
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-readlines

Comment: this methond slower than methond that's @Olivier L.

Comment: @HelloWorld Probably because it's deleting each preceding line from memory and loading in each line into memory. May be wrong, but Ruby's probably doing things properly (so that large files don't cause your script to crash).

Comment: Can you use `with_index` with this as well?

Comment: Yes, you can, e.g. `File.readlines(filename).each_with_index { |line, i| puts "#{i}: #{line}" }`

Comment: This method seems better. I am reading very large files and this way it doesn't crash the application by attempting to load the entire file into memory at once.

Comment: @HelloWorld Only if you the entire file fits into memory at once, otherwise this one will be faster or the only one that runs without crashing. Try each methods on a 1 GB file on a system with only 1 GB RAM.

Answer (score 441):

```
File.foreach(filename).with_index do |line, line_num|
   puts "#{line_num}: #{line}"
end
```

This will execute the given block for each line in the file without slurping the entire file into memory.  See: [IO::foreach](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/IO.html#method-c-foreach).

Comment: This is the answer - idiomatic Ruby and doesn't slurp the file. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/5546681/165673

Comment: All hail the Ruby gods!

Comment: how to go to second line inside the loop ?

Comment: You must use `'filename'` instead of `filename`. Also use `line_num+1` instead of `line_num` so first line begins in `1` and not in `0`.

Comment: @Smeterlink `filename` is a variable containing a string such as `'xxx.txt'`.

Answer (score 19):

Your first file has Mac Classic line endings (that’s `"\r"` instead of the usual `"\n"`). Open it with

```
File.open('foo').each(sep="\r") do |line|
```

to specify the line endings.

Comment: Sadly, there’s nothing like the universal newlines in Python, at least that I know of.

Comment: one more question, I have to use stdin, like ruby my_prog.rb < file.txt, where I can't assume what the line ending char the file uses... How can I handle it?

Comment: Olivier’s answer seems helpful, if you’re OK with loading the whole file into memory. Detecting newlines while still scanning the file will take a bit more work.

Answer (score 9):

I'm partial to the following approach for files that have headers:

```
File.open(file, "r") do |fh|
    header = fh.readline
    # Process the header
    while(line = fh.gets) != nil
        #do stuff
    end
end
```

This allows you to process a header line (or lines) differently than the content lines.

Answer (score 7):

It is because of the endlines in each lines.
Use the chomp method in ruby to delete the endline '\n' or 'r' at the end.

```
line_num=0
File.open('xxx.txt').each do |line|
  print "#{line_num += 1} #{line.chomp}"
end
```

Answer (score 7):

how about [gets](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-i-gets) ?

```
myFile=File.open("paths_to_file","r")
while(line=myFile.gets)
 //do stuff with line
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget that if you are concerned about reading in a file that might have huge lines that could swamp your RAM during runtime, you can always read the file piece-meal.  See "[Why slurping a file is bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189262/why-is-slurping-a-file-bad)".

```
File.open('file_path', 'rb') do |io|
  while chunk = io.read(16 * 1024) do
    something_with_the chunk
    # like stream it across a network
    # or write it to another file:
    # other_io.write chunk
  end
end
```