# how to read uploaded files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm giving user opportunity to upload their files. However, application is not saving those files into the database, it only needs to get informations out of it.

So from a form which looks like this:

```
= simple_form_for @channel, method: :post do |f|
    = f.input :name
    = f.input :configuration_file, as: :file
    = f.submit
```

come `params[:channel][:configuration_file]`

```
#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xc2af27c @original_filename="485.csv", @content_type="text/csv", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"channel[configuration_file]\"; filename=\"485.csv\"\r\nContent-Type: text/csv\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20140822-6972-19sqxq2>>
```

How exactly can i read from this thing? I tried simply

```
File.open(params[:channel][:configuration_file])
```

but it returns error

```
!! #<TypeError: can't convert ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile into String>
```

PS
Additional solutions for xml and csv would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Rails docs:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/UploadedFile.html

an uploaded file supports the following instance methods, among others:

```
open() 

path()

read(length=nil, buffer=nil)
```

you could try:

```
my_data = params[:channel][:configuration_file].read
```

to get a string of the file contents?

or even:

```
my_data = File.read params[:channel][:configuration_file].path
```

Also, if the file can be long, you may want to open the file and read line by line. A few solutions here:

[How to read lines of a file in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012930/read-lines-of-a-file-in-ruby)

If you want to read a CSV file, you could try:

```
require 'csv'    

CSV.foreach(params[:channel][:configuration_file].path, :headers => true) do |row|
  row_hash = row.to_hash
  # Do something with the CSV data
end
```

Assuming you have headers in your CSV of course.

For XML I recommend the excellent Nokogiri gem:

http://nokogiri.org/

At least partly because it uses an efficient C library for navigating the XML. (This can be a problem if you're using JRuby). Its use is probably out of scope of this answer and adequately explained in the Nokogiri docs.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/UploadedFile.html)

> The actual file is accessible via the tempfile accessor, though some
>   of its interface is available directly for convenience.

You can change your code to:

```
file_content = params[:channel][:configuration_file].read
```

or if you want to use the File API:

```
file_content = File.read params[:channel][:configuration_file].path
```