# Read a parameter from a file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara

I am trying to find out how can I read from a file, for example test environment.
The file contains:

```
test_env1 = "http://test.com"
test_env2 = "http://test2.com"1
```

Is possible to read from this file for `test_env1` to visit the assigned URL.

Comment: Yes. This information is everywhere. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157207/how-can-i-read-a-file-with-ruby

Comment: We need to see what you've tried. As is it looks like you're asking for us to write the code for you, instead of us helping debug problems with the code you wrote. As is, this question is dangerously close to being a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545068/what-are-all-the-common-ways-to-read-a-file-in-ruby