# How to read file into line by line array in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, file

I have a file data like this:

```
  productRankingOct12: [
  value: "LessPopularityEPC"
,
  value: "CtrEpcJob"
,
  value: "DeviceSpecificLPE"
]
guidedSearch: [
  value: false
,
  value: true
]
```

I would like to read the lines into array & store it like

```
array[0] = productRankingOct12: [
array[1] = value: "LessPopularityEPC"
```

Comment: There are numerous posts about reading a file line by line. For example, [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545068/what-are-all-the-common-ways-to-read-a-file-in-ruby). You can modify it slightly to load an array.

Comment: Your data file looks like no other I've ever seen. What's generating it? Are you *sure* that's how it actually looks? *WHY* do you want to read a file into an array? Is the file guaranteed to *always* fit into memory? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189262/.

Answer (score 3):

Use `File.readlines` ([inherited from IO](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-c-readlines)):

```
lines = File.readlines(filename)
```