# How to open and read a file in one line in ruby

Tags: ruby

How would this be written to be on a single line?

```
in_file = open(from_file)
indata = in_file.read
```

Comment: indata = File.open(from_file).read. from_file - path to file

Comment: Some examples here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545068/what-are-all-the-common-ways-to-read-a-file-in-ruby

Comment: "How would this be written to be on a single line?" – Use semicolon instead of newline. Always works, you can write *any* Ruby program, no matter how complex, in one single line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
File.read("/path/to/file")
```

It will read whole file content and return it as a result.

Comment: For more info on `File.read`, https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/IO.html#method-c-read 
`File` inherits `read` from the `IO` class.

Answer (score 1):

`open("README.md").read`

For very small file, this is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

To read ONE line you can use `File.readline`

Given:

```
cat file
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
```

In Ruby:

```
f=File.open("/tmp/file")

p f.readline 
# "Line 1\n"
```