# Parsing a dataset in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to read a dataset and parse that into the data I need. The file will consist of lines of strings like this:

```
id: 1234567 synset: test,exam
```

I want to then obtain the `id` number and the `synset` word. So in this case, I want `1234567` and `test,exam`

Here's what I've come up with, but I'm sure there are better ways.

```
File.open(synsets_file, "r") do |f|
    f.each_line do |line|
       id = line.split[1].to_i
       nouns = line.split[3]
       #do things with id and nouns
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is fine. You could use `split` once with this syntax :

```
File.foreach(synsets_file) do |line|
  _, id, _, nouns = line.chomp.split(/\s+/, 4)
  # do things with id and nouns
end
```

Using `4` as second parameter for [`split`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split) will ensure that `nouns` isn't split if there are spaces inside.

Answer (score 0):

If you will be reading large files it is better to use something like `foreach` instead of reading the entire file into memory:

```
File.foreach(sunset_file) do |l|
  id = l.split[1].to_i
  nouns = l.split[3]
  #do things with id and nouns
end
```

More information can be found in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545068/what-are-all-the-common-ways-to-read-a-file-in-ruby).  The third answer down discusses "slurping" a file and why it's not a good idea.

Edit: Removed JSON portion of answer.

Comment: Telling them to use another file format is not a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression

```
File.open(synsets_file, "r") do |f|
  f.each_line do |line|
      /^id: (?<id>.*) synset: (?<nouns>.*)/ =~ line.chomp

     puts id
     puts nouns

     # ...

  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using JSON format in the file, it will be easier for you. Then, you can do something like this:

```
require 'json'
file = File.read('file-name-to-be-read.json')
data_hash = JSON.parse(file)
puts data_hash['id'] // gives 1234567
```

Comment: You can try splitting the lines based on spaces. `line.split(" ")` This way, you will get an array.