# Extracting value from a file and setting value to attribute, in chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I wanted to extract value from a *file* and then put it into an attribute.

eg. let the file be `/app/ABC/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` 
and

the attribute be `default['sample_cookbook']['auth_keys']`

I would like the value(s) in *id_rsa.pub* set into the above attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545068/what-are-all-the-common-ways-to-read-a-file-in-ruby) for more information on how to read data from files.

For this case, since id_rsa.pub is probably only on the order of a few kB, you can just use

```
default = {'sample_cookbook' => {'auth_keys' => File.read("/app/ABC/.ssh/id_rsa.pub") }}
```

Comment: so, I understood your answer and wrote this following statement- It worked just fine. 

`default['sample_cookbook']['auth_keys'] = ::File.read("/app/ABC/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")`

Comment: Just remember that this happens when the file is executed, not when you use the attribute.