# Rails Plain Text Asset Extract String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, text, assets

Sorry, I am just learning how to use Rails.

I've got a simple .txt file asset which I would like to pull random Strings from to display on my landing page.

Is there an easy way in Rails to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545068/what-are-all-the-common-ways-to-read-a-file-in-ruby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming each string is in a separate line, you can do this:

```
strings = File.readlines('path/to/file.txt')
```

Then, to get a random string use `sample`, like this:

```
strings.sample
```

If you wan't more than one random string, just use `sample` with an argument, for example:

```
strings.sample(3)
```

This will return an array with 3 random lines from `strings` array.

Finally, you can do all in one line, for example, try this in the controller:

```
@string = File.readlines('path/to/file.txt').sample
```

And you will have `@string` available to use in the view.

Comment: Works like a charm, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So you are not giving me much. but I am going to assume that you want to get 1 line of a text file.

This is how I would do it

```
File.readlines("my/file/path.txt").sample
```

I hope that get you started :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks, I do like your solution better