# How to read a file after it's been written to in Ruby

Tags: ruby

When I run the following code taken from the [*Learn Ruby the Hard Way Course* Exercise 16](https://learnrubythehardway.org/book/ex16.html),

```
filename = ARGV.first
target = open(filename, 'w+')

puts "Now I'm going to ask you for three lines."

print "line 1: "
line1 = $stdin.gets.chomp
print "line 2: "
line2 = $stdin.gets.chomp
print "line 3: "
line3 = $stdin.gets.chomp

puts "I'm going to write these to the file."

target.write(line1 + "\n" + line2 + "\n" + line3)

puts "And now I'm going to print the file to prove I have altered it."
puts target.read

puts "And finally, we close it."
target.close
```

the line `puts target.read` does not print the three input lines, even though the text file does change.

I have tried changing the mode used by the `open` method and adding a new `open` method before calling the `read` method. Creating a separate program with the same script to read and print text file works as expected.

How can I read a file I have just written to? Why does it not work when I write and read within the same program?

Answer (score 4):

> why does it not work when I write and read within the same program

The answer is that when you write to a file, your IO stream is set to the end of where you have written. When you read, it continues from this point. In this case, after writing, you have reached the end of the file and there is nothing else to 'read'. You can use [IO#rewind](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/IO.html#method-i-rewind) to reroll to the beginning and print out what was just written to through the IO Stream.

```
filename = 'Test.txt'
target = open(filename, 'w+')

text  = '12345'
target.write(text) # target points to EOF
# Note that if you print target.write(), it will tell you the 'index' of where the IO stream is pointing. In this case 5 characters into the file.

puts "And now I'm going to rewind the file"
puts target.rewind # go back to the beginning of the file.
# => 0
puts "And now I'm going to print the file to prove I have rewound it."
puts target.read # read the file, target now points to EOF.
# => '12345'


target.close
```

Answer (score -2):

```
File.open("my/file/path", "r") do |f|
  f.each_line do |line|
    puts line
  end
end
```

File is closed automatically at end of block
It is also possible to explicitly close file after as above (pass a block to open closes it for you):

```
f = File.open("my/file/path", "r")
f.each_line do |line|
  puts line
end
f.close
```

Credit to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5545284/8328756

Comment: Why not marking as duplicate instead of copying an answer? (nice you at least gave credit though)

Comment: Didn't know how to do that so I just added and gave credit. Sorry.

Comment: This doesn't explicitly answer the question of how to read and write within the same block.

Comment: In case you still don't. you can read [the flagging help](/help/flagging). And we usually recommend to new users to do the [tour](/tour)