# how to invoke many files and get info one by one

Tags: ruby

I have posted a question here [how to extract specific information from many text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49451446/how-to-extract-specific-information-from-many-text-files?noredirect=1#comment85907585_49451446)

Someone commented that I must break the question to smaller peaces and try then to combine them in order to get my answer

So I have 200 txt files in a folder in my desktop. I want to read them one by one and search for specific information

Now I want to get the information from one txt file in a folder. the example text file is in the other question and that is why I did not post it here to avoid replicate.

Someone proposed that I do it as follows: which I could not figure out how to set it up. I did as follows but it did not really work

```
Dir.glob('files/*').each { |path| file = File.open(path) }
```

here is what I personally do

```
for file in /Users/admin/Desktop/*.txt; do
    while read -r line; do
        echo "$line"
    done < "$file"
done
```

so it reads all the files that are txt in my folder and print each line

now my question is how to extract specific info from them. I want to extract the following information from each file

```
          HEAT OF FORMATION       =        -25.54241 KCAL/MOL =    -106.86944 KJ/MOL
          TOTAL ENERGY            =       -444.38126 EV
          ELECTRONIC ENERGY       =       -840.31531 EV
          CORE-CORE REPULSION     =        395.93406 EV
          GRADIENT NORM           =          0.91931 = 0.45965 PER ATOM
          DIPOLE                  =          2.66600 DEBYE    POINT GROUP:       C2v 
          NO. OF FILLED LEVELS    =          6
          IONIZATION POTENTIAL    =         10.352991 EV
          HOMO LUMO ENERGIES (EV) =        -10.353  0.402
          MOLECULAR WEIGHT        =         30.0262
          COSMO AREA              =         60.70 SQUARE ANGSTROMS
          COSMO VOLUME            =         42.52 CUBIC ANGSTROMS
```

Comment: yep, this is better. Still a bit too broad for my taste, but it is more answerable now. Let's see if there are any takers.

Comment: Does each file have all of this info? Or you need to hunt for these parameters across different files?

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev all files have these info

Comment: So, the multi-file aspect can be ignored for now? First you need to learn how to extract info from _one_ file, worry about other files later.

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev absolutly right

Comment: Simplify/narrow down the question further then :)

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev done!

Comment: @Casper Please read my question more carefuly. I have given the example data in the first question , please read my question carefuly . It seems like you just read the comments

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with the CSV class, you just need to include it.

```
require 'csv'

txt_file = File.read("your_file_name_here")
CSV.parse(txt_file) do |row|
  <do work here>
end
```